# Async Issue for DbContext used in constructor of objects created via DI

Tags: entity-framework, async-await, dbcontext

I wonder if someone can clarify when to await and when not to. Consider this code

```
public Task<List<User>> GetUsersForParent(int someParentId)
{
    var qry = Context.Users.Where(u=>u.parent = someParentId)
                   .OrderBy(u=>u.Surname)
    return FilterActive(qry);
}


//Actually in a generic base class, but not important (I don't think)
protected Task<List<T>> FilterActive(IQueryable<T> query) where T: BaseEntity
{
    return query.Where( q=>q.Active == true ).ToListAsync();
}
```

Then it is used like this

```
var users = await DbHandler.GetUsersForParent(1);
```

So the calling method is awaited, but the others are not. Is this correct?

Should the method calling the ToListAsync() be awaited? (this I assume is now doing the work)

My reason for this is I am getting the DbContext is being used by a second thread dreaded exception. I am running out of places to look. My understanding is the methods are building up the whole task which is executed, but could this be messing with the dbContext?

### Edit re DbContext error

Having narrowed down the potential locations for the issue, via Debug.Print and SQL Query profiling (just in case that helps anyone else) I can see one statement being profiled (the next in profile is logging the exception) and I can see two methods being run via the debug print.

One of these methods is a PermissionsManager which, when constructed, initialises itself and loads the user data. This is constructed when requested via the DI framework.

The other method is the single query on the OnGet() method for the page. It is running a single query to get an entity by ID, it is awaited correctly.

My working theory at the moment is that the Thread running the DI construction and another thread running the Page initialise are colliding.

When I made the PermissionManager just `_person = new Person() // await db.users.get(userid)` the issue goes away. I could replicate the issue 1 in 2 or 3 times of refresh, and with that commented I could not replicate, despite refreshing the page 30+ times.

So my real question with async / await is probably more about DI injection and is that construction running on a different thread? if so, any best practice to avoid?

Comment: We do not allow solutions to be edited into the question. Please post it as an answer in the space below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the calling method is awaited, but the others are not. Is this correct?

I generally recommend using the `async` and `await` keywords, and [only return the tasks directly if the method is extremely simple](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

> My reason for this is I am getting the DbContext is being used by a second thread dreaded exception. I am running out of places to look. My understanding is the methods are building up the whole task which is executed, but could this be messing with the dbContext?

No. At least, the code you posted cannot cause that exception. Whether the `async`/`await` keywords are used, or whether the tasks are returned directly, the methods are asynchronous and they do not attempt to do more than one thing on the dbcontext at once.

It's possible that your problem is further up the stack. `Task.WhenAll` is a good thing to search for when tracking this down.

Comment: I did already find a few WhenAll (first venture into Await/async and far to eager to run in parallel) Though it wasn't a [visible] issue until upgrading EF... Reading your blog post now for inspiration

Comment: I have narrowed it down via lots of debug statements to an issue with the DI. I have a PermissionManager which is constructed by DI and as part of construction loads the user from the dbContext. I will updated the question (as getting complex to explain here.)

Answer (score 0):

> Should the method calling the ToListAsync() be awaited? (this I assume is now doing the work)

If you `await` the contents of either method you will be returning the result type, not `Task` of result type which means the execution cannot be deferred.

Your error will be coming up because you either have multiple threads interacting with the same instance of DbContext, awaited or no this would cause problems, that or you have some code calling the `ToListAsync()`-containing method, or another async DbContext operation without awaiting.

Writing an EF data access layer returning `Task` is fairly dangerous which can shoot you in the foot very easily.

Given your code structure I would recommend a couple small changes:

```
public async Task<List<User>> GetUsersForParent(int someParentId)
{
    var qry = Context.Users.Where(u=>u.parent = someParentId)
                   .OrderBy(u=>u.Surname);
    qry = FilterActive(qry);
    return await qry.ToListAsync();
}

protected IQueryable<T> FilterActive(IQueryable<T> query) where T: BaseEntity
{
    return query.Where( q=> q.Active == true );
}
```

Notably here I would avoid returning `Task` to reduce risks of improper use and potentially intermittent bugs. The base-class method for FilterActive can return `IQueryable<T>` to apply the filter without triggering the execution of the operation. This way `FilterActive` can be applied whether you want a List, a Count, or simply do an Exists check.

Overall I would recommend exploring patterns that return `IQueryable<TEntity>` rather than `List<TEntity>` etc. as the later results in either a lot of limitations for performance and flexibility, or requires a lot of boiler-plate code to handle things like:

- Sorting,
- Pagination,
- Getting just a Count,
- Performing an Exists check,
- Configurable filtering,
- Selectively eager loading related data, or
- Projection to generate efficient queries

Doing this with methods that return `List<TEntity>` either results in very complex code to support some of the above considerations, has these operations applied post-execution leading to heavier queries than would otherwise be needed, or requires a lot of near-duplicate code to handle each scenario.

Comment: Thank you for the input. The main reason for the FilterActive doing the return was to ensure every method used it to ensure some filter was added. Eg checking the tenantId matches, or only active results shown. I have different overloaded FilterActive methods to return list, entity, etc. I'll try encapsulating the Tasks within the data layer and see if that can cure this error.

Comment: Yep, the FilterActive method can still fulfill that role returning `IQueryable`, it merely moves the `ToList` out so that Filter just does that, apply a common filter, rather than applying a filter and triggering a `ToList`, executing the query. The repository & it's base class can compose the query through `IQueryable` then execute the desired action (`ToList`, etc.) to build the return value if still returning thinks like `List<TEntity>`. Ultimately, the fewer Tasks being passed around, the fewer openings for threading errors.

Comment: Is there not an issue using await in a method not marked as async (and therefore not returning a task)?

Comment: Sorry, my bad with the example. I have corrected it. Using an awaited async operation should have left the method async & Task. Keeping the common filter `IQueryable` allows it to work with both sync and async methods. Async is suited to more expensive queries where sync is faster for simpler ones.

Comment: So just to clarify my understanding then. Since the DB methods cannot be run in parallel, it is better to use the await just before returning the final result, which would prevent anyone trying any funky stuff like Task.WhenAll on a set of methods?

Comment: Correct. If you do want parallelism in some areas then each thread needs its own scoped DbContext. This means that entities returned from parallel tasks need to be completely detached, or better, projected to POCOs.

Answer (score 0):

So the constructor thing was a red herring. It was a missing await after all, just not where expected and in code that was unchanged.

I tracked down the culprit. There was a method in the basePage which hooked into the Filter of MVC pages. It took the user and loaded their permissions, however, since this loading of user permissions was made async, this method did not get awaited (it didn't need it before as was synchronous). I moved it to one of the async events on the page life cycle and all seems happy now (with a suitable await!). So it was a missing await, but the moral of the story is any time you make a sync method async, check what the heck is actually using it!